# How do i rename a script in RFT ? Renaming deletes the entire content of the script?

Tags: rename, rft

I have created a RFT script using Add empty script option.

And added my code which processess some logic..
Now when I rename the script the code which I have written is gone and is replaced with empty script and the file is renamed. Why does this happen? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of RFT are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, renaming preserves all of your code. It might be some issue with the Simplified Scripting, it often screw things if you manually edit the code. I suggest to [turn it off in the preferences](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405134).

This appened to me, with many other minor problems, I'm giving this advice by experience.

Comment: Good! I also suggest to keep your scripts under version control, so you can recover when encountering such problems. Can you accept my answer? Thanks