# opening mozila through RFT

Tags: rft

## Code:

```
import resources.Script4Helper;
import com.rational.test.ft.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.SAP.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.WPF.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.dojo.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.siebel.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.flex.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.generichtmlsubdomain.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.script.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.value.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.vp.*;
import com.ibm.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.sapwebportal.*;

public class Script4 extends Script4Helper
{
     public void testMain(Object[] args) 
    {

        setSimplifiedScriptLine(1); //firefox.exe: Mozilla Firefox Start Page - Mozilla Firefox                         
        timerStart("firefoxexeMozillaFirefoxStartPageMozilla_1");                           
        setSimplifiedScriptLine(2); //Click  Mozilla Firefox Start Page - Mozilla Firefox  Index  17  
        mozillaFirefoxStartPageMozilla().click(atIndex(17),atPoint(257,55));

        setSimplifiedScriptLine(3); //Type  Value  google.com{ENTER}
        mozillaFirefoxStartPageMozilla2().inputKeys("google.com{ENTER}");

        timerStop("firefoxexeMozillaFirefoxStartPageMozilla_1");                
    }
}
```

How to run this script? When i run this, this does not open the browser. It says "could not find mozilla"..

Can someone help with this??

Answer (score 0):

In the script I don't see any statement that says  start Browser or start Application.
Also, it seems the browser is not enabled and the html controls are getting recognised as windows controls.
In RFT you can use Simplified Scripting (that you are using currently) , and also Java scripting. This can be configured in the preferences. Or with the new version of RFT it can also be selected while creating a script.

You can manually edit the script to insert code snippet to start the browser. RFT help would have the documentation on  startBrowser()and startApp() APIs .

-Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide on how to configure Mozilla Firefox.
http://www.xcarecrows.com/eclipse/doc/Xcarecrows4SMV/current_version/html/userGuide/RFT%20-%20configure%20mozilla.html

Note that you have to use very old Firefox Versions (up to 3.6). In your code you have to start the app by name using `startApp("Firefox");` before doing any action in the browser.

I suggest to disable the Simplified Scripting, as it's very annoying
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243216/423955